# Enroll in all publicly available MOOCs

Tags: mooc

A disappointingly [high](https://www.class-central.com/report/coursera-old-platform-shutdown-download-courses/) number of [MOOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course)s cannot be joined after the course is over. I'm looking for a program, browser extension or userscript that can enroll me into all publicly available MOOCs. I am mostly interested in Coursera, and edX.

Any price, OS, license and browser is fine.

Comment: Enroll when? On request (e.g. click) or automatically whenever you start the browser?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Either is fine.